# Alternatives to PHP built-in server

Tags: php, web-services, server, development-environment

I am a PHP developer, From last 3 months i am using PHP's built-in server for testing my tools and apps. But its single threaded and it hangs now and then.
So is there any alternatives with multi-threads and faster and important point is there any server which can be run on command exection and kill it by command.

I am searching for Lightweight server which can be installed without any root/administrator access.

Comment: Go for Apache or Nginx rather.

Comment: @Frank I dont have enough permissions to make apache fit my requirements. I am not system administrator.

Comment: I have looked into Mongoose, but i dont understand how to work with it.

Comment: Use a vagrant/virtualbox and you can set up as many virtual machines as you want to, using whatever webservers you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try IIS (Internet Information Services) its primarily used on Windows Server grade operating systems but you can use the Express version which you can install on Windows 7, 8 and even 8.1, however you will need admin privileges, if you want something that does not there are portable Apache bases web servers that can be on a USB or flash drive and used anywhere. 


[USB WebServer 8](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/) is one that I use often it runs Apache on port :8080 but is easily changeable it also comes with a portable but full MySQL DB server with phpMyAdmin.


Have a look at the [Mongoose User Guide](http://cesanta.com/docs/Usage.shtml) it is quite simple to setup.

Happy Web Deving 
Nimesh

Comment: USB Webserver 8 can only be run on windows, i need cross platform software.

Comment: What Operating systems are you looking to run this on? Is it just OSX and Windows? If so I would recommend Xampp [link](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) As of my knowledge they do support a USB version, but you may have to do a little googling